# Can I create an HDF5 link to a hyperslab?

Tags: hdf5, h5py

Is it possible to create a link to just a hyperslab of a dataset in HDF5?

For example, I have one dataset of size 1000 x 3, representing (a,b,c) as a function of time, let's say.  And now I want a link that points just to the 'a' data (1000 x 1).  Is this possible?

[Having googled this extensively, I learned the valuable lesson that "link" is essentially useless in a google query.  And I can't tell from the HDF5 documentation, so I'm sorry if this is stupid.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having asked at the (very helpful) HDF5 helpdesk, I find that the answer is no.  For anyone else looking for this functionality: redesign your code/data structure.

Unfortunately for me, the code is not mine, and the data structure is set by other, stubborn people.